# PHP Javascript Web Page Sync using cookie

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web page to be created that will read data via serial port which needs to be updated in a web page. My approach is to have a PHP script that will monitor in an infinite loop of incoming data from serial port. Once received it would just update a cookie . The web page will read the update cookie and update its content.

Is my approach possible to implement? I am not sure how to sync a cookie by name both from PHP and Javascript - one does not read until other finishes writing.

```
<?php
setcookie("user", "My Name", time()+3600);
?>
```

Now in a web page at setInterval method I need to read the cookie.

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
} 

getCookie("user");
```

Now that I have cookie data I can update the web page by calling reload() JS method.

Is my approach correct - will this approach work - what are the things I should take care?

Comment: I would use `if (c.indexOf(name)!==-1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);` as `indexOf()` will return `-1` if it can't find the key. So that condition runs if it found the key in the string.

Comment: Thanks but will this approach or rather design has any constraints? Will this design work?